# 2 same class elements show only one at a time

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have one `div` element and inside this elements there are 2 `input` boxes for month and year. And for validation I'm using `jquery validate`.

> On `validate` event, I want to show only one
>   `label.error`. Example. If month label is visible year label hidden
>   and vice-versa.

Because when both error message come together the input are increase and it looks odd.

[**Please find fiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/we7rkrxk/2/)

> Please click on submit to see the message.

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) { 
        $(element).parents('.form-group').prepend(error);
    },
    submitHandler: function() {
    },
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {

        $('label.mylable').hide();
        $('label.error').show();

    }

});
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $("#login_details").validate({ 
        ignore: [],
        rules: { 
            login_expiryMonth: {
                required: true,
                digits: true,
                minlength:2,
                maxlength:2
            },
            login_expiryYear: {
                required: true,
                digits: true,
                minlength:2,
                maxlength:2
            },

        },
        messages:{

            login_expiryMonth: {
                required: 'Please enter a date',
                digits:   'Please enter a valid date',
                minlength:'Please enter a valid date',
                maxlength:'Please enter a valid date'
            },
            login_expiryYear: {
                required: 'Please enter a date',
                digits:   'Please enter a valid date',
                minlength:'Please enter a valid date',
                maxlength:'Please enter a valid date'
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a placeholder element, then if the error is for one of those textboxes populate the placeholder element instead -

```
<div id="error-msg">
```

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) { 
    var id = $(element).prop('id');        
    if(id =='login_expiryMonth' || id == 'login_expiryYear') {
        $('#error-msg').html(error);
    }
    else {
        $(element).parents('.form-group').prepend(error);
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/tbpc0smm/1/)